# How to find the recurrence formula of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, big-o

I'm currently talking an algorithms class and really struggling to understand how to even come up with recurrence formulas.

say i have a a double nested for loop algorithm for finding the sum of numbers stored in a 2d array. I know the overall runtime is something like n^2. But how do i come up with a recurence equation to prove that this algorithm is n^2?

My professor always starts off with some kind of math T(0) = 0 or T(1)=1. Then T(n) = n^2. I'm lost when it comes to what work I'm suppose to be showing.

```
public static int sum2dMatrix(int[][] matrix, int a, int b)
{
  int sum=0;
  for (int i=0; i<=a; i=i++)
  {
    for (int j=0; j<=b; j=j++)
    {
       sum +=matrix[i][j];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

The actual question for the assignment is "Give an example of an algorithm that has running time Ө(n^2). Give detailed time performance analysis."

Is it as simple as saying its just a*b (the detentions of the array)? In worst case if a=b then n^2 additions would take place.

Comment: I am not sure the concept of recurrence equations is related to matrix sum as you have indicated. I guess you may be mixing the concepts of recurrence equations, recursive functions and run-time complexity.

Comment: I think you're right. I probably am. The actual question is "Give an example of an algorithm that has running time Ө(n^2).  Give detailed time performance analysis."

Comment: Take a look at:http://www.slideshare.net/sajidmarwatt/how-to-calclute-time-complexity-of-algortihm?related=1

Answer (score 0):

You can see that for this program its about a*b, because it iterates through every element of your matrix.  You can indicate the behaviour of algorithm, but there isn't an exact calculation.
It its because not every PC has same arhitecture. So you can say its is about n^2

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, but it seemed too obvious perhaps.